# Compilation error in eclipse due to apprate plugin cordova

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to install the following 2 plugins into my cordova app. I am able to install and compile the project however when I import in eclipse I find the following error.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The declared package "org.pushandplay.cordova.apprate" does not match the expected package "org.apache.cordova.apprate" AppRate.java    /myApp/src/org/apache/cordova/apprate   line 1  Java Problem
```

Attached is the screen shot:

[image]
[image]

**Edit:**

```
package org.pushandplay.cordova.apprate;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;

public class AppRate extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException
    {
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();

            if (action.equals("getAppVersion")){
                callbackContext.success(packageManager.getPackageInfo(this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
                return true;
            }
            if (action.equals("getAppTitle")) {
                ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0);
                final String applicationName = (String) (applicationInfo != null ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "Unknown");

                callbackContext.success(applicationName);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            callbackContext.success("N/A");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Utpal

Comment: How have you installed the plugin? Are you saying that when you run `cordova run android` or `cordova build android` you have no error and you have this error only when importing in Eclipse? In this case it would be very strange...

Comment: Yes, I have no errors when I run the project using CLI. But this error shows up in eclipse.

Comment: Forgot to mention it's an ionic project..

Comment: show your code in AppRate.java. how you declare your package name.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin here we go..